# Ruby Axlsx: How to get values from another worksheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

If I have two worksheets and I am trying to access values from another worksheet. Is there a way from axlsx gem that can do that?

```
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Table A".excel_worksheet) do |sheet|

end

wb.add_worksheet(name: "Table B".excel_worksheet) do |sheet|

end
```

If I am inside worksheet B right now, and want to perform some calculations using the values from table A (for example rows in A). Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, first keep the sheet A around, and secondly use that when you add the chart on sheet B.

```
sheet_a = wb.add_worksheet(name: "Table A".excel_worksheet) do |sheet|
  # ...
end

wb.add_worksheet(name: "Table B".excel_worksheet) do |sheet|
 sheet.add_chart(Axlsx::BarChart, start_at: 'A1', end_at: 'F10', title: 'Chart from Table A', ) do |chart|
    chart.add_series data: sheet_a["$'Table A'.$B$2:$F$20"]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
sheet_a = wb.add_worksheet(name: "Table A") do |sheet|
  sheet
end

wb.add_worksheet(name: "Table B") do |sheet|
   puts sheet_a.name
end
```

Comment: I see. But my question is if I decide to access the `rows` values from sheet_a in b, I would do something like `sheet_a.rows` right? But the value I got from `sheet_a.rows` in sheet b is different from the value I got from `rows` in sheet A? I got a huge response from `sheet_a.rows`. Any idea why?